# Tensorflow : use of Caching device

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning

I am currently working with tensorflow in a multi-gpu setting, training a model on multiple GPUs, using multiple towers as done in the multi-gpu part of https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn.

All the weights of the model are shared across all towers, and for this purpose, placed in cpu memory. To do so, specific device placement are used everywhere in the code where a variable is created/reused (with tf.get_variable).

I was looking for a way to place all variables on cpu in a more convenient way and stepped upon the caching_device argument in [variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) and was wondering if it is what i am looking for, but i am still not sure as the corresponding weights in the graph has ops placed on gpu corresponding to the device placement used at creation, plus a read operation on cpu.

Do you have informations on the concrete use of caching_device, what is actually happening, where the variable is really placed ?

Thanks.